# Using list data to define download parameters for drive.files.export Google Drive API V3 using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

My app can successfully list and download (export text/plain) a file, from Google Drive to my local hard drive, using separate functions `listFiles()` & `downloadFile()` (extensively using code from [Nodejs Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs)

I am trying to combine this code into a function that will download (export text/plain) of all files listed in the folder.

At this point my file and path references are 'hard coded' in for testing (one file/one path)

So I am trying to understand how any modified listFiles() code could loop through the available list of files and provide the next available fileId as a reference for the downloadFiles() code. I also wanted to provide the matching fileName for path building.

In my listFiles() I cannot seem to find much information on parsing the returned promise data stream. So I've just got a dumb version going. Which can only download 1 file. (this is my understanding of the code)

```
/**
 * Lists names and IDs of pageSize number of files (using query to define folder of files)
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
 function listFiles(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

    drive.files.list({
        corpora: 'user',  
        pageSize: 1,
        // files in a parent folder (drive>ocrTarget ID) that have not been trashed  
        q: `'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' in parents and trashed=false`,    
        fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
      }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const files = res.data.files;
        if (files.length) {
          files.map((file) => {
            console.log(file);  
          });
        } else {
          console.log('No files found.');
        }
      });
    }
```

Output

```
PS C:\Users\blah\blah\gDriveDev> node . myNodejsScript
{
  id: 'xxxx file id of only file that could be listed with PageSize: 1 xxxxx',
  name: 'Copy of 31832_226140__0001-00007'
}
```

I have gone through Google Drive for Developers Drive API (V3) docs (Guides/Reference) Which, cover request parameters. However I want to manipulate the data type/structure of output. eg walk the file list and parse the fileId.

(i)
Before I got my download code working properly I was creating metadata files of a JSON layout type. Now I have no idea how I did this. They were saved according to my file/path settings like this:.

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "name": "atest.txt",
 "mimeType": "text/plain"
}
```

(ii)
During experiments, running working code, I found that files.length has a value that equals the number of files listed in the available PageSize:

(iii)
For `files.map((file)` it looked like I was dealing with a Map object [MDN Map Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) But error messages in my test code showed that it was not.

(iv)
I have seen the following type of code used for accessing parameters:

```
let data = 'Name,URL\n';

res.data.files.map(entry => {
  const { name, webViewLink } = entry;
  data += `${name},${webViewLink}\n`;
});
```

But I don't have the knowledge to interpret this in order to evaluate it for my situation.

If anyone can make a suggestion, for my situation, it would be appreciated.

-------------------- [Added to question] --------------------

To summarize I understand from the following:

```
const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
       files.map((file) => {
```

- `length` property is the number of files
- `files` produces list of length x length (x lists of x files)
- `file` produces a list of the files (id, name)

How do I index these results? Do I have to read each of the file details from the list into an array?

Some examples of output here:

```
console.log(Object.keys(file)); // a list of file key types
```

output

```
[ 'id', 'name' ]
```

and

```
console.log(file);
```

eg

```
    {
  id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  name: 'Copy of 31832_226140__0001-00007'
}
```

But the keys are not numbered. So there is no numerical reference (index) available.

My aim: read the full list of file names available and supply these for each file to be downloaded.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. You are struggling to read the response data from your listFiles() request? But which data exactly are you intereste din and what would you like to do with this data?

Comment: Thank you for reading @ziganotschka I have added a further explanation to the question.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your issue correctly, but I provided a solution according to what I understood.

Comment: @ziganotschka Thank you. This helped. I have incorporated your files.foreach code into a more precise question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70585181/15542245

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop with an index**

Sample:

```js
const files = res.data.files;
var ids = [];
if (files.length) {
    files.forEach(function (file, i) {
        ids[i]= file.id;
    })
}
```